# Intuition/meaning behind/physical content of the concept of a smooth structure

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, soft-question, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, intuition

Some mathematical structures are visualized very well. I imagine how a shapeless bunch of points (a set; the only property of which is quantity) is collected in one or another soft form (topological space), depending on what topology is set on it. I imagine how this soft (floating) shape becomes hard when I set the metric. The first examples of deformation retractions give a vivid geometric intuition of the homotopy type as a "(homotopy) framework". Thus, the concepts of homotopy type, topology, and metrics have a clear physical content. In contrast to these three examples, for the concept of a smooth structure on a manifold, everything is not so clear due to the fact that manifolds up to dimension 3 have a unique smooth structure

> Do you have any intuition for a smooth structure on a manifold? Do you
> see any meaning/physical content in it? Do visually homeomorphic
> non-diffeomorphic spaces differ for you?

After a smooth manifold is provided with additional structures (Riemannian,  symplectic, etc.), the meaning of these objects becomes clear. But a smooth manifold devoid of additional structures is still very mysterious for me.

P.S. I'm not sure if this question is for a forum (on the other hand, the system showed me many questions with similar titles). If so, then feel free to close it.

Comment: Is it that different from "visualizing" a function (of one real variable, say) which is continuous but not differentiable?

Comment: Probably yes, because the smoothness of a function is a property, and "the smoothness of a manifold" is an additional structure. At least continuous non-smooth functions themselves are easy to visualize, for example $|x|$.

Comment: I think the question is not about the distinction between manifolds that have or don't have smooth structures, or between maps of manifolds that are or aren't smooth, but given a manifold that does have *at least one* smooth structure, what do the different ones mean. A related question is "what's the simplest example of two distinct smooth structures on a given topological manifold ?"

Comment: @MaximeRamzi: maybe the two questions are not so separate, since whenever you have two smooth manifolds that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic, any homeomorphism gives a continuous, non-differentiable function.

Comment: As for the "simplest example", there are at least two candidates: 
1. $3\mathbb{CP}^2\#20\overline{\mathbb{CP}}\vphantom{C}^2$ and $K3\#\overline{\mathbb{CP}}\vphantom{C}^2$;
2. $S^7$ and $\{v^2+w^2+x^2+y^3+z^7 = 0\} \cap S^9 \subset \mathbb{C}^5$.

Comment: @MarcoGolla : wow I had no clue $S^7$ had such a simple exotic smooth structure, thanks !

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418707/intuition-meaning-behind-physical-content-of-the-concept-of-a-smooth-structure#comment1074967_418707), the smoothness of a manifold is an additional structure (on the topological manifold, I guess), whereas the smoothness of a function is an additional structure on its domain—there's no way to tell from a bare function, i.e., abstract set of ordered pairs such that …, whether or not it is smooth.

Comment: @AivazianArshak: There is a smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $g(x)= |x|$ is differentiable. Namely consider the homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $f(x)=-x^2$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=x^2$ if $x\geq 0$.  The map $f$ induces a smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $g$ is differentiable (as g(f(x))=x^2). Of course in this case $\mathbb R$ with the standard smooth structure and $\mathbb R$ with the smooth structure induced by $f$ are diffeomorphic. But I still think that gives insight into what a smooth structure does. This is the comment of Marco Golla above.

Comment: @ThomasRot I don't understand what you want to say. You just renamed the points. The same $|x|$ under the new name (according to the translation by $f$) is also not smooth. I said in my comment that the smoothness of a function is a property of the function (and the physical meaning of the smoothness of a function is perfectly clear; we think of more or less all macrophenomena in nature as smooth). But a smooth structure on a manifold is an additional structure (which has nothing to do with the smoothness of a function). It is not very clear what it corresponds to in nature.

Comment: The smoothness is not a property of a function on a manifold. It depends on the smooth structure. We typically choose the standard smooth atlas on $\mathbb{R}$,but I chose a different one. The two smooth structures are diffeomorphic in this case.

Comment: @ThomasRot I understand it. I don't understand what this has to do with the conversation. Sam Hopkins obviously meant that $\mathbb{R}$ has a fixed standard differential structure and asked to what extent my question differs from the visualization of a continuous non-differentiable function.

Comment: @ThomasRot Analogy: the question "how to think about whether a function is an isometry or not" (it's clear how to think - "preserve distances" is an initially intuitive idea) is not related to the question "how to think about what information a metric stores" (which also seems fine intuitively). However, whether a given set-theoretic function is an isometry or not depends on the metrics on dom-e and cod-e.

Comment: Since you can recover the smooth structure of a manifold from the ring of smooth functions, the question is indeed equivalent to finding a continuous function that is smooth wrt to one differentiable structure but not wrt to the other one.

Comment: @AivazianArshak I think you are putting a bit too much faith in your visualizations. For example, adding a metric to a shape does not make it "hard", it just restricts the ways in which it can bend. For example a cylinder minus a line is isometric to a flat rectangle. You only get "rigidity" in the intuitive sense if you are talking about invariance under rigid motions in R^n. 

Same with topological spaces: thinking of them of points collected in a "soft form" may be a comforting idea, but topological spaces can be incredibly pathological, and it would be easy to destroy this intuition.

Comment: @AivazianArshak My point is: visualization is nice, but not always helpful. The kinds of spaces that admit different smooth structures are far, far away from "physical intuition". I really do think the right answer to your question is to show functions that are smooth under one choice, but not another, then "look" at what those functions are like. That will build intuition for how smooth structure can vary. 

My secondary point is that you may not want to trust the current visualizations you like: they don't necessarily contain useful or accurate information.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$The purpose of a manifold structure is to be able to differentiate functions. And initially we know how to differentiate functions only if the domain is an open set in $\R$. Moreover, once you know how to differentiate functions, this opens the door to doing all the other stuff you do with manifolds.

Here's how I think of it: Initially, think of a manifold as just a set $M$ and nothing else. Think of a coordinate map as a bijection $\phi: O \rightarrow \R^n$, where $O\subset M$ and $\phi(O)$ is an open subset of $\R^n$. An atlas is a collection of coordinate maps such that the domains of the coordinate maps cover $M$. No assumptions on topology or differentiability yet.

A topological manifold is $M$ with an atlas $\mathcal{A}$ such that for any two coordinate maps $\phi_1: O_1 \rightarrow \R^n$ and $\phi_2: O_2 \rightarrow \R^n$ such that $O_1\cap O_2\ne \emptyset$, then the map $\phi_2\circ\phi_1^{-1}: \phi_1(O_1\cap O_2) \rightarrow \phi_2(O_1\cap O_2)$ is a homeomorphism. Notice that such an atlas immediately defines a topology on $M$ where the domains of the coordinate maps in $\mathcal{A}$ form a base of open sets. Assume that this topology is Hausdorff, and you have a topological manifold.

A smooth manifold is defined in exactly the same way, except you assume that the change of coordinate maps, $\phi_2\circ\phi_1^{-1}: \phi_1(O_1\cap O_2) \rightarrow \phi_2(O_1\cap O_2)$, are smooth.

Clearly, a smooth manifold is a topological manifold. If you start with a topological manifold, extend its atlas to a maximal atlas, then you can ask whether there is a subatlas (i.e., a subset of coordinate maps) that satisfies the definition of an atlas of a smooth manifold. If so, you say that the topological manifold is smoothable.

There is no reason why there couldn't be two different smooth subatlases of a topological manifold. And, if there are two such subatlases, there is no reason why they should be compatible with each other. In other words, if you have a coordinate map $\phi_1: O_1 \rightarrow \R^n$ in the first smooth atlas and a coordinate map $\phi_2: O_2 \rightarrow \R^n$ in the second smooth atlas, it does not necessarily follow that $\phi_2\circ\phi_1^{-1}: \phi_1(O_1\cap O_2) \rightarrow \phi_2(O_1\cap O_2)$ is smooth. It is homeomorphic, since both lie in the topological atlas.

Now, to make things even more complicated, it is possible that there is a global homeomorphism $\Phi: (M,\mathcal{A}_1) \rightarrow (M,\mathcal{A}_2)$ that is a smooth diffeomorphism of the two apparently different smooth manifolds. So, even though the two subatlases are incompatible, they actually define two smooth structures on $M$ that are diffeomorphic.

Finally, we say that a topological manifold has more than one smooth structure on it if there are two smooth subatlases such that no map $\Phi$ as described in the previous paragraph exists.

Comment: Oops. I forgot return to functions. You can now say that a function $f: M \rightarrow \R$, where $M$ is a smooth manifold, is smooth if $f\circ\Phi^{-1}: \phi(O) \rightarrow \R$ is smooth for any coordinate map $\phi$. The assumption on the change of coordinate maps is the necessary and sufficient condition that you don't run into any logical inconsistencies in this definition.

Comment: I understand this (and love the language of sheaves), but it does not answer the question of what physical idea the notion of smooth structure captures.  Imagine two homeomorphic non-isometric metric spaces.  You see how they differ.  Imagine two homeomorphic non-diffmomorphic manifolds.  Do you see how they differ?

Comment: Alas, I didn't really answer the question you asked. Unfortunately, I don't see any physical intuition for two homeomorphic but non-diffeomorphic manifolds. Notice that this is a global concept. In general, there will exist diffeomorphisms between dense open subsets of the two manifolds that can be extended uniquely as homeomorphisms that are not diffeomorphisms.

Comment: MathJax note: As unpleasant as it is, you have to write `$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$The purpose …`, not `$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$ The purpose …`, or your text will have a spurious space.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice, thanks!

Comment: @AivazianArshak You ask how two homeomorphic non-diffeomorphic manifolds differ. If you have a homeomorphism at hand, they differ by having different sets of smooth functions. So if you can visualise a non-smooth function, you are done. But if you only know that the two manifolds are abstractly homeomorphic, then you need some kind of differential-topological insight to tell you they cannot be diffeomorphic. In a few cases, one can compute some invariants like the Eells-Kuiper invariant for 7-spheres. But I have no clue how to visualise those. Locally, every manifold is smoothable.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Wow, you've moved the question in a very good and specific direction! Apparently, a large list of non-topological invariants of smooth manifolds and their intuition would be a satisfactory answer. Thanks a lot!